# How to access host network from a container form docker stack?

Tags: docker, docker-network

How do you access for example the url `http://<host>:80` apache running on the docker host from a running container?

i.e. the docker container ip is 10.0.0.3 and the host is 192.168.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

## Description

Create a bridge and map the bridge as an external network in the docker compose file

## Command line

docker network create -d bridge --subnet 192.168.0.0/24 --gateway 192.168.0.1 dockernet

## Stack mapping

a stack is deployed from a yml file docker compose

networks:
    dockernet:
       
      external: true